# Normed induced by inner products and the parallelogram law

Tags: functional-analysis

**Question**: Show that the following space is not an inner product space.

Let $Z = (\mathbb{R}^3,\Vert\cdot\Vert_*)$ where $\Vert x \Vert_* = |x_1|+\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2}$

My attempt:

Take the vectors $x=(2,-1,2)$ and $y=(-1,1,0)$ so that
$\Vert x+y \Vert_*^2 = \Vert (1,0,2)\Vert_*^2 = (1+2)^2 = 9 $ and

$\Vert x-y \Vert_*^2 = \Vert (3,-2,2)\Vert_*^2 = (3+\sqrt{8})^2$ and the sum of these is

$\Vert x+y \Vert_*^2+\Vert x-y \Vert_*^2 = 9+(3+\sqrt{8})^2 = 26+6\sqrt{8}$ ---(*) and

$\Vert x \Vert_*^2 = (2+\sqrt{5})^2 = 9+4\sqrt{5}$ and

$\Vert y \Vert_*^2 = 4$  so that

$2(\Vert x \Vert_*^2 +\Vert y \Vert_*^2 ) = 2(4+9+4\sqrt{5}) = 26+8\sqrt{5}$---(**)

and thus $Z$ is not an inner product space since it does not satisfy the parallelogram law.

*I have tried to show this using multiple different vectors but somehow they do satisfy the parallelogram law*

Is this correct? Is there any other way in which I can show that this is not an inner product space?

Comment: Restrict to vectors $(x_1,x_2,0).$ Then the norm takes the form $|x_1|+|x_2|.$  Vectors  $1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ do not satisfy the parallelogram identity

Comment: Understood! Appreciated